# How i can solve this problem "systemctl start mariadb"

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3, mariadb-connect-engine, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.1

I am facing this error

> root@localhost:~# systemctl start mariadb Job for mariadb.service
>   failed because the control process exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
>   details.

```
root@localhost:~# systemctl status mariadb
    ● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.22 database server
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor pre>
         Active: inactive (dead)
           Docs: man:mysqld(8)
                 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
```

Answer (score 0):

use systemctl enable mariadb.service

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302261/systemd-unit-activate-vs-enable

Give a good description on how to set things up